# How to get the first term from a custom field?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

working with wordpress, having a custom taxonomy field "authors" in which I enter multiple names for every single publication such as (Mark Twain, Isabelle Lagard, Tony Band), when i use this code :

```
<?php
$object_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'auteur', array('fields'  => 'all'));
if ($object_terms) {
    echo '' . '', . '' ;
    $res = '';
    foreach ($object_terms as $term) {
        $res .= '' . $term->name . ', ';
    }
    echo rtrim($res,' ,').'' . '';
}
?>
```

I can get all the names of the authors for every publication.
But, what i have to do to make this code show only the full name of only the first author?

Comment: May be i am wrong. befor foreach just try echo rtrim($object_terms->fields->name,' ,').'' . '';

Comment: it worked when putting it after foreach but it shows the first word. actually i need it to show the first full name please

Comment: Your code is working. that u wana say?